# Hash Table initializing

Tags: perl, shell

I have a .pl file which i edited a bit but when i try to run it i get this error

```
Use of uninitialized value within %dca in concatenation (.) or string at ./createWindow.pl    line 65.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./createWindow.pl line 64.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./createWindow.pl line 64.
Use of uninitialized value within %dca in concatenation (.) or string at ./createWindow.pl line 65.
```

The Code for the following is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $window=$ARGV[0];
my $windowCentral=$ARGV[1];

my $sep=$ARGV[2];

my @pairs=`cat $ARGV[3]`;
chomp @pairs;

my @pssm=`cat $ARGV[4]`;
chomp @pssm;

my @predSS=`cat $ARGV[5] | cut -d, -f1`;
chomp @predSS;

my @predSA=`cat $ARGV[6]`;
chomp @predSA;

my @predRCH=`cat $ARGV[7]`;
chomp @predRCH;

my @predCN=`cat $ARGV[8]`;
chomp @predCN;

my @seq=`cat $ARGV[9]`;
chomp @seq;

my @prop=`cat ../propensity.txt | cut -d\\  -f1,3`;
chomp @prop;
my %prop;
foreach(@prop) {
        my @v=split(/ /);
        $prop{$v[0]}=$v[1];
}
my @dca=`cat $ARGV[10]`;
chomp @dca;
my %dca;
foreach(@dca) {
        my @v=split(/ /);
        $dca{"$v[0],$v[1]"}="$v[2],$v[3]";
}

my $count=0;
foreach my $pair (@pairs) {
    my @values=split(/,/,$pair);
    next if($values[2]<$sep);
    $count++;
    my $r1=$values[0]-1;
    my $r2=$values[1]-1;
    my $central=($r2-$r1)/2;

    #separation between contactd
        print "$values[2],";
    #propensity
        my $AApair=$seq[$r1].$seq[$r2];
        print "$prop{$AApair},";
        #sequence length
        my $num=@seq;
        print "$num,";
    #dca
        my $posPair="$values[0],$values[1]";
        print "$dca{$posPair},";


    #PredSS of windows around contact residues
    &dumpWindow($r1,$window,@predSS);
    &dumpWindow($r2,$window,@predSS);
```

The rest of the code works fine but i cant figure out indexing the dca hash table. 
You need all four columns of the file, not just the 1st, 3rd and 4th, so 
don't do the cut.

```
my @dca=`cat $ARGV[10]`;


> chomp @dca;
> my %dca;
> foreach(@dca) {
>          my @v=split(/ /);
>          $dca{$v[0]}=$v[1];
> }
```

The key to the hash table has to be the concatenation of the 2 residue 
indexes, and the value the concatenation of the 3rd and 4th columns:

```
$dca{"$v[0],$v[1]"}="$v[2],$v[3]";
>
>          my $AApair=$seq[$r1].$seq[$r2];
>          print "$dca{$AApair},";
>
```

To index the hash table you need r1 and r2, not the amino acids in those 
positions.

```
my $posPair="$values[0],$values[1]";
print "$dca{$posPair},";
```

indexing the dca hash table in the wrong way. Look at how you are filling it up from the .contact file a few lines of code above. 
Stuck at this for Ages now.....

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite clear: You are trying to concatenate a value for a undefined hash key value and you're trying to print it.

First of all, I take it that you have `use strict;` and `use warngings;` on?

What you need to do is test your code before you do the concatenation and print. This could be an error, and maybe you might want to print out a debugging statement to help you find the problem.

```
if ( not defined $value[$r1] or not defined $values[$r2] ) {
   print "DEBUG: Whoops! I have a problem...\n";
   no warnings qw(uninitialized); #DEBUG: 
   say qq(DEBUG: \$posPair = \$value[$r1] . \$values[$r2]);
   say qq(DEBUG: \$posPair = $value[$r1] . $values[$r2]);
   use warnings qw(uninitialized);
else {
    my $posPair = $values[$r1] . $values[$r2];
    print "$dca{$posPair},";
}
```

The `no warnings qw(uninitialized)` will turn off the warning you're getting. This is just temporarily done so I can see my debug statements. The `use warnings qw(initialized)` turns those warnings back on (which is what you want).

This will give you a clue to what's going on. What is the value of `$r1` and `$r2` at this point? Are both undefined, or is it just one and not the other?

There's a logic flaw in your code, and printing out debugging statements is a good way to quickly locate the issue. Perl does have a debugger, but I find adding a few statements here and there can more quickly can identify the problem than using the debugger.

If you take this approach, you need to add this line with your other `use` statements:

```
use feature qw(say);
```

This will give you the use of the `say` command. This is like the print statement, but it automatically does a new line at the end. It makes adding a debug statement much easier. You just duplicate the line you want, and add `say qq(DEBUG: ... );` around the entire line. You can then put a backslash in front of variable names you might not want to interpolate.

A final step is to use [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) to the mix. You can print out your entire data structure this way which can also help show you logic flaws.

Comment: What makes adding debugging easier is not using `say` instead of `print` but using `warn`...

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma - I see why `warn` would be good. It will output to STDERR which is nice. Plus, it gives you something to search for when you want to remove the statements. I like `say` because I don't need to put in the `\n` at the end. I can duplicate the line, and add in `say qq(DEBUG: ...);` around the line. In fact, I even have it as a VIM macro. I guess if I went that far, I could have used warn and `\n` on the end.

Comment: `warn` prints the line number at which the warn appeared at the end and then a newline. warn "something\n" would defeat the purpose somewhat as it does not print the line number.

Answer (score 1):

1) you are defining my @dca and my %dca. Its better to avoid duplicating the same name...

2) print "$dca{$posPair},"; change to   print "$dca->{$posPair}";

I would define your hash variable as reference to hash instead of hash itself. After this you can try pointing to your keys. I would update few lines in your code. Please look on this example:

```
my $dca = {};
#then populating dca keys:
$dca->{"$v[0],$v[1]"}="$v[2],$v[3]"; #please note , char which is missing in later usage.

#and how to get your values:
my $posPair=$values[$r1].','.$values[$r2]; #I added missing coma here.
print "$dca ->{$posPair},";
```

Comment: 1 2 0.311808 0.199348
1 3 0.310089 0.236611
1 4 0.344717 0.130342
1 5 0.449746 0.0971291
1 6 0.346515 0.194622
1 7 0.310089 0.207573
1 8 0.310452 0.195762

Comment: This takes an input from file which has 4 columns. going to try ur code now

Comment: Global symbol "$dca" requires explicit package name at ./createWindow.pl line 43.
Global symbol "$dca" requires explicit package name at ./createWindow.pl line 65.
Execution of ./createWindow.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Did you changed @dca name to something different? I guess this is your problem. Additionally please check in what scope are you defining your hash.

Answer (score 1):

Your are populating the hash with keys like : `"$v[0],$v[1]"` and you are reading it with keys like `$values[$r1].$values[$r2]`

change the line

```
$dca{"$v[0],$v[1]"}="$v[2],$v[3]";
```

to

```
$dca{"$v[0]$v[1]"}="$v[2],$v[3]";
```

Comment: @user2689506: In which way it didn't work? Could you show us some example of input? Where does `@pairs` come from?

Comment: All inputs are from different files in different folders. There is createwindow.sh which calls createwindow.pl and there are multiple files.

Comment: I get this error for ur Code

Global symbol "$dca" requires explicit package name at ./createWindow.pl line 65.
Execution of ./createWindow.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @user2689506: You can't have this error with the code you've shown. Provide us the real code that throw this error.

Comment: ya this is not the whole code .... its just the part thats causing problems... All other code in the file is not mine and everything work fine when run without my additions. 

My added lines are the DCA part

Comment: You need all four columns of the file, not just the 1st, 3rd and 4th, so 
my @dca=`cat $ARGV[10]`;
> chomp @dca;
> my %dca;
> foreach(@dca) {
>          my @v=split(/ /);
>          $dca{$v[0]}=$v[1];
> }
The key to the hash table has to be the concatenation of the 2 residue indexes, and the value the concatenation of the 3rd and 4th columns:

$dca{"$v[0],$v[1]"}="$v[2],$v[3]";

To index the hash table you need r1 and r2, not the amino acids in those positions.

my $posPair="$values[0],$values[1]";
print "$dca{$posPair},";

Comment: @user2689506: Try to dump `%dca` just after you've populated it (ie `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%dca;`). Then print `$posPair` to see what it contains before using it. And see if that key exists in %dca.